# Link to a Twitter profile using the internal ID rather than the screen name

Tags: twitter

In my application I have the internal integer ID of a Twitter user and I want to provide a link to their Twitter page, e.g. I have an ID of 123456 for the Twitter account http://twitter.com/thisisanexample and I want to provide a link that resolves to the Twitter account page using the ID.

I know I could query Twitter's web services using the ID and get the screen name but I'd rather not if possible.

Does anyone know if Twitter provides a URL that takes the internal integer ID of the user and redirects to the normal user Twitter profile?

Comment: Twitter doesn't provide a URL resolving feature that automatically converts ID's to names and re-directs you. There simply isn't a feature like this from Twitter. You can use [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) of course and get JSON.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Update: **No longer works**

---

Yes. Example:

http://twitter.com/account/redirect_by_id?id=783214

Comment: This doesn't appear to currently work for mobile devices, twitter's site is adding mobile to the url.

Comment: This option was canceled - https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-redirect-to-a-user-profile-with-its-user-id/22646